# tensorflow: segmentation error in multiple threads

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, tensorflow

I build a RNN network using the python ops rnn provided. But it sometimes runs into the error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` and sometimes performs well. The output message says `Direct session inter op parallelism threads: 8`, but actually it creates 25 threads. And when I run it on another computer with fewer threads (parallelism threads: 4, actual threads 9), it never occurs this error. I wonder if this error is related to multiple threads and how can I solve it?

I used a python module 'faulthandler' to print more error messages:

`Thread 0x00007f1047bf9700 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 339 in wait
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168 in get
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/summary_io.py", line 197 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810 in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783 in __bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f10db79b740 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 428 in _do_run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 368 in run`

Comment: There are Python threads (driving different queue runners), Eigen threads (for multi-threaded ops), threads used to launch Compute calls (inter-op threads) and some other threads for book-keeping, so you'll have more than 8 threads. But things shouldn't segfault, if you can have a way to reproduce it consistently it would be worth filing a bug.

Comment: BTW, segfault happens inside C++ code, so faulthandler wouldn't help. More useful is to analyze the "core" file with gdb, and get backtrace (bt command in gdb), you might see which op is producing the crash

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that the bug is not reproducible and the probability of segfault is about 20%. I'll try to use gdb.